# Need advice on binary logs?

Tags: mysqlbinlog, binlog

We have set up master slave configuration and we are storing bin logs of 30 days. It is taking up more space on server and we need find some better way to handle it.

We are thinking to store logs of 7 days only. Is it OK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how often I do it.  Just make sure you do a full-database backup every 7 days, and rsync or copy the binlogs to an off-site location more frequently.